# Null value of javascript variable after initialization

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this html

```
<lu id="balancingSel" >
   <li><a href="bal.html"> "VALUE1" </a></li>
   <li><a href="bal.html"> "VALUE2" </a></li>
   <li><a href="bal.html"> "VALUE3" </a></li>
   <li><a href="bal.html"> "VALUE4" </a></li>
</lu>
```

I want to get the value when on of those list elements is clicked
and pass it to another function as you can see below.

Currently i am trying this in my **bal.html**

```
<script>
var projectType;

$(function () {
   
    //Initialize project name
    var ul = document.getElementById('balancingSel'); //Parent
    ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.tagName === 'A')
            projectType = e.target.innerText;
    });

    //Load data
    balancingTableLoad($("#balancingFileSelect").val(), projectType);
    fillInputFieldData($("#balancingFileSelect").val(), projectType);
    });
</script>
```

The issue is that although the value is set to variable projectType when the two other functions are called with that variable as parameter it is undefined.

I tried moving the variable declaration inside the function but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code call the two function even before you click anything, the reason being addEventListener, runs after clicking and those two function execute as soon as they are defined.

```
 ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.tagName === 'A')
            projectType = e.target.innerText;
     // }); oringally the function addEventListener ends here

    //Load data
    balancingTableLoad($("#balancingFileSelect").val(), projectType);
    fillInputFieldData($("#balancingFileSelect").val(), projectType);
    }); // addEventListener should end here
```

Comment: I am new to this, why the two functions are executed before ?

Comment: addEventListener, is only run when you click, the outer functions run on load, the two methods are inside the outer function not inner addEventListenerfunction

Comment: Thank you for helpfull answer! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the function calls inside the `if` block, otherwise `projectType` could be not set:

```js
function balancingTableLoad(val, type) {
  alert(type);
}

function fillInputFieldData(val, type) {
  alert(type);
}

$(function() {

  //Initialize project name
  var ul = document.getElementById('balancingSel'); //Parent
  ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
      projectType = e.target.innerText;
      //Load data
      balancingTableLoad($("#balancingFileSelect").val(), projectType);
      fillInputFieldData($("#balancingFileSelect").val(), projectType);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="balancingSel" >
   <li><a href="bal.html"> "VALUE1" </a></li>
   <li><a href="bal.html"> "VALUE2" </a></li>
   <li><a href="bal.html"> "VALUE3" </a></li>
   <li><a href="bal.html"> "VALUE4" </a></li>
</ul> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```